# Lenovo X1 Yoga - Ubuntu 18.04: Suspend not working and multiple errors

Tags: kernel, 18.04, suspend, touchpad, lenovo

I experience problems with Ubuntu 18.04 running on Lenovo Yoga X1.

After the laptop comes back from suspend, the touchpad is very laggy, and the laptop must be restarted to fix the issue.

Furthermore, I get error messages from crashed system components regularly.

The kernel is `4.15.0-30-generic`.

How can I make my system stable? Will updating the kernel fix such issues?

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded the firmware to the most recent versions?  You can use `fwupdmgr` to automatically update much of this, but for the touchpad (on my X1 Carbon 7 gen) which stopped working after suspend, I needed to download an iso image and follow the instructions here:

https://tojaj.com/lenovo-biosuefi-update-from-usb-stick-i-e-without-bootable-cd/

The BIOS update can be found here:

https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds540232

(For 7th generation, search for the approprate version for your system)